# How do you use the Caps-lock keyboard in Pro Tools?

Tags: midi, pro-tools

I can't seem to get the Caps-lock keyboard in Pro Tools to work.. I even have had trouble with my midi keyboard; so maybe I'm just having all around trouble with midi input. Anyway, both the Caps-lock keyboard, and my usb keyboard work with Logic.

I'm running OS X 10.6.8, and working with Pro Tools 9.0.5

So, does anyone know what might be wrong..?

Comment: I'm not sure what a Caps-lock keyboard means in this context. Are you trying to use a QWERTY computer keyboard (which has a caps lock on it) to enter MIDI notes?

Comment: Yep. Just like you can do in Logic Pro 9.